# Creating histograms in pandas with columns with equidistant base, not proportional to the range

Tags: python, pandas, histogram

I am creating an histogram in pandas simply using:

```
train_data.hist("MY_VARIABLE", bins=[0,5, 10,50,100,500,1000,5000,10000,50000,100000])
```

(train_data is a pandas df).

The problem is that, since the range `[50000,100000]` is so large, I can barely see the small ranges `[0,5]` or `[5,10]` etc. I would like the histogram to have equidistant bars on the x-axis, not proportional to the range. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
bins = [0, 5, 10,50,100,500,1000,5000,10000,50000,100000]
df.groupby(pd.cut(df.a, bins=bins, labels=bins[1:])).size().plot.bar(rot=0)
```

Demo:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10**5,(10**4,2)),columns=list('ab'))
bins = [0, 5, 10,50,100,500,1000,5000,10000,50000,100000]
df.groupby(pd.cut(df.a, bins=bins, labels=bins[1:])).size().plot.bar(rot=0)
```

[image]

filtering results:

```
threshold = 100
(df.groupby(pd.cut(df.a,
                   bins=bins, 
                   labels=bins[1:]))
   .size()
   .to_frame('count')
   .query('count > @threshold')
)

Out[84]:
        count
a
5000      396
10000     492
50000    4044
100000   4961
```

plotting filtered:

```
(df.groupby(pd.cut(df.a,
                   bins=bins, 
                   labels=bins[1:]))
   .size()
   .to_frame('count')
   .query('count > @threshold')
   .plot.bar(rot=0, width=1.0)
)
```

[image]

Comment: Very good answer! Any way I can make the bars contiguous (without blanks in between?)

Comment: @user, thanks! What do you mean? Do you want to skip bars where `count == 0`?

Comment: You see in your pics that the bars have a fixed width. I want that size (the width) larger so that the bars are attached to each other. If that is possible.

Comment: @user, just play with the `width` parameter when calling `.plot.bar()` starting from `width=1.0` and reducing the value...

Comment: That worked fine. This is a great answer, thank you for adding the .query with a threshold, even though I did not ask. Very helpful.